# Angular JS, put json to ng-repeat out of an event fails

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am new to Angular and I have this issue that I don't get solved. I have read today alot about good style and $scope soup but I could not find an answer to this.

It is the following, very easy example:

I have a controller with an ng-repeat inside and an input with a change-event.

```html
<div id="searchbar" data-ng-controller="SearchCtrl">
  <input id="search" autocomplete="off" data-ng-model="search" data-ng-keyup="getResults( search );" />

  <div id="input_results">
    <li data-ng-repeat="x in names">
      {{ x.Country }}
    </li>
  </div>

</div>
```

When I assign some json directly from the controller function everything works fine.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);




var SearchCtrl = function($scope, $http, HTTPService) {

  console.log("Control opened");

  $scope.names = [{
    "Country": "TEXT"
  }];
};
```

When I try to assign json out of the event, then I receive there "parent is null"

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);




var SearchCtrl = function($scope, $http, HTTPService) {

  var _this = this;
  
  console.log("Control opened");
  
  $scope.getResults = function(searchstring) {
    
    console.log("Execute search: " + searchstring);
    
    $scope.names = [{
      "Country": "TEXT"
    }];
    
    _this.getResults(searchstring, $scope, $http);
  };


};
```

I don't know how I can pass the correct scope to getResults() or how to solve this issue. Additionally I have read that it is best to use dots in model names like SearchStrl.search to avoid shadowing.

I am also confused about the behaviour, when I change $scope.search it works fine inside the getResult() function, but why not with the ng-repeat.

It would be nice if somebody could explain me the reason for this behaviour.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your ng-repeat code fails to work because he doesn't has an array to repeat on through.the code only creates the array after you activated 'getResults' function.

in your controller you shold have something like this:

```
app.controller('CTRL1', function($scope){
    $scope.names = [{
        "Country": "TEXT"
    }]; //your array

    $scope.getResults = function(search) {
        //your search code.
    }
})
```

I can see you're trying to make a list of items with a search. instead of the above code I will suggest you do as followed:

```
<div data-ng-controller="SearchCtrl">
    <input data-ng-model="search" /> <!-- creates a search instance- -->

<div id="input_results">
    <!--filter by search model -->
    <li data-ng-repeat="x in names | filter: search"> 
        {{ x.Country }}
    </li>
</div>
```

and in your code:

```
$scope.names = [{
  "Country": "TEXT"
}];
```

Comment: As I said. The example data is shown correctly by ng-repeat within the controller but not in the getResults() function. The json data is fine. I just don't get the point with a the right scope and how to come there. I don't want to filter the data via Pipe in the frontend. That is not my point. I want to feed the ng-repeat out of an event where I cannot reach it at the moment.

Comment: because that getResults() hasn't been called yet your ng-repeat fails to find an array to repeat on. try put the array in the conroller and a diffrent array in the function. Also try the code i gave you you might find it to solve your problem

Comment: Maybe there is a misunderstanding. I am passing the searchstring to the server to get the search results and then I want to output the incoming json to the ng-repeat which fails. I call the event and then the error occurs.

Comment: if you are getting the entire array at first. copy my HTML code and just $scope.search = 'search string' in your function. if you have to make an http request you need to just change your array. if that doesn't work you're gonna have to remove/add objects to your array using push() and splice() methods.

Comment: sorry, but you don't get the point. All I am confused about is how to access the $scope.names inside the getResults() - event, so I can change the value of $scope.names inside the getResults()-event, so it affects ng-repeat and shows the results after they were received from the server.

Comment: How about initializing `$scope.names = []` *outside* the handler, then update the array when the handler is executed (clear the array and put the received results)? It is what I do usually (meaning, well, that it works that way :-P).